# Structured linked list to an array

Tags: c, arrays, pointers, malloc

```
typedef struct node {
    int value;
    struct node* next;
}node;

int* to_array (node* ll, int size) {
    int i = 0;
    int* arr = malloc(size*sizeof(int));
    while (ll) {
          arr[i] = ll->value;
          ll = ll->next;
          i++;
    }

return arr;
}
```

Can someone please explain why

```
int* arr = malloc(size);
```

will give us an array? I thought when we have pointers we cannot change it individually like `arr[i] = 5` or something.

Answer (score 5):

Your is actually a very good question.  Granted, one that's already been asked and answered many times on SO.  But a good question nonetheless.

From the C/C++ FAQ:

> http://c-faq.com/~scs/cgi-bin/faqcat.cgi?sec=aryptr
>
> Arrays are not pointers, though they are closely related (see question
>   6.3) and can be used similarly (see questions 4.1, 6.8, 6.10, and 6.14).

1. When you declare an array (e.g. `int a[5]`), you've allocated storage for five "int" elements.  You can access each element like `a[i]`.
2. When you declare a pointer (e.g. `int *b`) you haven't allocated *ANY* storage.
3. You can declare and initialize a pointer at the same time:

   ```
   int *b = NULL;  /* Initialize to 0 */
   ... OR ...
   int *b = malloc (5 * sizeof (int)); /* Allocate storage for 5 "int" elements */
   ```
4. When you declared array `a`, you allocated space from the stack.  The allocation cannot be changed.

   When you declared `b`, you allocated the *SAME* amount of space, but you allocated from the heap.  Further, you can change `b` to point to anything else, at any time.  You can also `realloc()` your memory to change the size of your storage.
5. Just as you can use index syntax `a[i]`, you use exactly the same syntax `b[i]`.

This link might help explain: http://www.geeksforgeeks.org/g-fact-5/

PS:
When you "have pointers", you most definitely *CAN* "change it individually like `arr[i] = 5` or something".

Comment: Thank you. I appreciate your detailed explanation! I understand it now.

Answer (score 2):

`int *arr = malloc(size * sizeof(int));` does not give an array, it gives you a block of memory large enough to hold `size` integers.

The `arr[i] = ll->value;` statement uses *pointer arithmetic*: an expression `arr + 5` means take the memory address of the integer pointed to by `arr` and move 5 positions on from there. Now, because the compiler knows that it is working with `int` pointers, and assuming 32-bit `int`s, it will know to add 20 (=5*4bytes) to the value of `arr` to find the 6th element.

Next, the C language has the syntactic sugar where the expression `arr[5]` is equivalent to `*(arr + 5)`.

This is also why arrays in C are indexed from 0, and why the name of a C array can also be used as a pointer to the first element of the array.

Answer (score 1):

In this statement

```
int* arr = malloc(size*sizeof(int));
```

function malloc allocates an extent of memory that is capable to store `size` objects of type `int` and returns pointer to this extent (or to the first slot in the extent where an object of type int can be accomodated) as having type `void *` that is implicitly converted to type `int *` because in the left side of the declaration identifier `arr`  has type `int *`.

According to the C Standard (6.5.2.1 Array subscripting)

> 2 ...The definition of the subscript operator [] is that E1[E2] is
>   identical to (*((E1)+(E2))). Because of the conversion rules that
>   apply to the binary + operator, if E1 is an array object
>   (equivalently, a pointer to the initial element of an array object)
>   and E2 is an integer, E1[E2] designates the E2-th element of E1
>   (counting from zero).

Thus this expression

```
arr[i]
```

is evaluated like

```
*( arr + i )
```

where in the subexpression

```
arr + i
```

there is used the pointer arithmetic that is this expression points to i-th element in the allocated extent of memory.

If you have an array declared for example like

```
int array[size];
```

then in this expression

```
array[i]
```

the array name is implicitly converted to pointer to its first element. You may imagine it like

```
int *p = array;
*( p + i )
```

Thus if you have the following declarations

```
int array[size];
int *p;
```

then the following statements are equivalent

```
array[1] = 10;
```

and

```
p = array;

*( p + 1 ) = 10;
```

Becuase operation `array + i` is commutative then you can write interchangeably

```
array[i]
```

and

```
i[array]
```

For example in your function you could write

```
i[arr] = ll->value;
```

Though it would only confuse readers.:)

Beginners always wonder when see code like this

```
int a[10];

0[a] = 5;
```